# Does Hazelcast support bulk set or asynchronous bulk put operation?

Tags: hazelcast

I have a use-case of inserting a lot of data during big calculation which really don't have to be available in the cluster immediately (so the cluster can synchronize as we go).

Currently I'm inserting batches using *putAll()* operation and it's blocking  and taking time.
I've read [a blog post](http://blog.hazelcast.com/2014/04/08/performance-top-5-1-map-put-vs-map-set/) about efficiency of *set()* operation but there is no analogous *setAll()*. I also saw *putAsync()* and didn't see matching  *putAllAsync()* (I'm not interested in the future object).

Am I overlooking something? How can I improve insertion performance?

EDIT: Feature request: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/5337

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right, they're missing. Could you create a feature request, maybe you're also interested in helping to implement them using the Hazelcast Incubator?

Comment: Ok. I will create the feature requests and see if I can help with implementation effort.

Comment: @noctarius may you take a glance here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369352/get-started-with-hazelcast-sourcecode?noredirect=1#comment48830581_30369352 please?